# In Django, How do you write the url pattern for '/' and other root-based urls

Tags: django, url, routes, url-pattern

I'm new to django, and one of the things that I'm still learning is url_patterns. I set up a pages app to handle the root path (http://www.mysite.com) as well as some static pages such as the about page. I figured out how to set up the url pattern for the root path, but I can't get the site to direct the path '/about' to the pages "about" view.

Here is my main urls.py

```
 from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
 from django.conf import settings
 urlpatterns = patterns('',
     url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
     url(r'^$', 'pages.views.root'),
     url(r'^/', include('pages.urls')),
  )
```

here is my pages urls.py

```
 from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
 urlpatterns = patterns('pages.views',
      url(r'^about', 'about'),
 )
```

Here is my pages views.py

```
 # Create your views here.
 from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
 from django.template import RequestContext
 from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
 from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

 def root(request):
    return render_to_response('pages/root.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))
 def about(request):
    return render_to_response('pages/about.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

If I change the main urls.py file to have `r'^a/', include('pages.urls')` then the path '/a/about' directs to the about action.. so I think it has to be an issue in the way i'm writing the url pattern in this file. But, I can't figure out how to change it. Can anyone help?

Comment: to the people voting to close this question, would you mind being more constructive and comment to let me know what guideline's are not being met, and/or how i could edit this question to better satisfy these requirements?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Figured out what the issue is. The proper url_pattern on the project level is:

```
 urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^$', 'pages.views.root'),
    url(r'', include('pages.urls')),
 )
```

When this is in place, '/about' and other simple paths direct properly.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: I would like to add for anyone else who missed it: `pages` is an application in OP's project, not a Django-specific syntax. It could have been `other_pages` or something similar.

Comment: This! When I first created my project, I mistakenly interpreted the project level url_pattern as an app in itself. It seems the correct design is to have a dedicated app for all web page content as well as any other specific apps. Is this correct?

Answer (score 7):

Try this, for url.py on the project level:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Examples:
url(r'^$', 'apps_name.views.home', name='home'),

# Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
# url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

(r'^about/', include('about.urls')),
)
```

and then the url.py for the app about

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', direct_to_template, {"template": "about/about.html"}, name="about"),
)
```

Take into account that regular expression are evaluated from top to bottom, then if the path fits the regexp it will enter. To learn more about regexp google it or try the great book from Zed Shaw about [regexps](http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/book/)

Answer (score 4):

Note that from Django version 2.0 the URL pattern has changed to use  `django.urls.path()` Check Example here: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial03/)

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /polls/
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /polls/5/
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

About the `url` method:

```
url(r'^$', 'pages.views.root')
```

`url` is deprecated in Django 3.1, it's good to use `re_path` instead.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#s-url

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#re-path

Note: The `r'^$'`pattern WON'T work with `path` function, and will give you a misleading error that the route could not be found.

You have to use `re_path(r'^$', [etc])` every time you use a regular expression instead of a simple string in pattern.